# Problem while passing data between multiple view controllers using push pop navigation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My work is 
1 .Passing data from first view controller -> second view controller using pushViewController: Success

2 .Passing data from second view controller -> First View Controller using popViewController: Success //used delegate protocol for return data

3 .Passing data from third view controller -> First View Controller : Error

Code :
 ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,secondViewDelegate,thirddelegate {

    @IBOutlet var Firstoutput: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var inputField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func popdata(value: String) { //second view controller delegate protocol defintions
        Firstoutput.text = "\(value)"
    }
    func thirdView(datas:String) //third view controller delegate protocol definition
    {
        print(datas)
    }
    @IBAction func pushBtn(_ sender: Any) { //first view button action

      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vcFirst = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as! SecondViewController //secondview

        vcFirst.Secondtext = inputField.text

        vcFirst.delegate = self //second view delegate intiate

        let vcThird = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "third") as! ThirdViewController //third view

        vcThird.thirddelegate = self //third view delegate intiate

        navigationController?.pushViewController(vcFirst, animated: true)
    }
}
```

SecondViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
//protocol for passing data when pop
protocol secondViewDelegate {
    func popdata(value:String)
}
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var secondOutputField: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var secondInputField: UITextField!

    var Secondtext:String!

    var delegate:secondViewDelegate!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        secondOutputField.text = Secondtext

    }
    //popping back to first view controller using data
    @IBAction func popBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        if delegate?.popdata != nil
        {
        delegate.popdata(value: secondInputField.text!)
        }
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    //pushing to third view controller
    @IBAction func thirdPageBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vcThird = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "third") as! ThirdViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vcThird, animated: true)
    }

}
```

ThirdViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
protocol thirdviewDelegate //delegate to pass data from thirs view to first view
{
    func thirdView(datas:String)
}
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    var thirddelegate:thirdviewDelegate!

    @IBOutlet var thirdTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad
    }


    @IBAction func thirdViewInvoke(_ sender: Any) {
        if thirddelegate?.thirdView != nil
        {
        thirddelegate.thirdView(datas: thirdTextField.text!)
        }
    }


}
```

OutPut Screenshot : 
[image: Pushing data no problem]
[image: Popping data no problem]
[image: Pass data from Third to First view Controller but its not passing value]

Only passing data from third to first view controller is not working help me to solve this issue...Thanking you

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: you need to pass data from 3rd VC to Second VC first, then move data from Second VC to first One.  thirdPageBtn function has no reference of protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NotificationCenter` to receive data.

On press of your Get Data button in your `ThirdViewController`, post your `notification`.

```
let myDataToPass : [String: Any] = ["myData" : yourStringValue]
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("getDataPressed"), object: myDataToPass)
```

In your `FirstViewController`, add observer in `viewDidLoad` that will listen for the `notification`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receiveInitialDetails(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("getDataPressed"), object: nil)
}

//once the notification is received, this function will be called and you can get the data that you passed in thirdVC using notification.userInfo
@objc func receiveInitialDetails(notification : Notification) {
     let data = notification.userInfo as! [String:Any]
     let yourStringValue = data["myData"] as! String
     // you have your data here. downcast it to your desired data type.
}
```

Comment: but showing warning inside receiveDetials : 
Cast from '[AnyHashable : Any]?' to unrelated type 'S

Comment: Pass your object as Dictionary, and then fetch it value in `receiveInitialDetails ` updated the code

Comment: fatel error while printing : print(yourStringValue)

Answer (score 1):

you can implement it by using `notification center`

below I give a small example how I pass imageDataDict in my project

```
  let imageDataDict:[String: UIImage] = ["image": image]

  // Post a notification
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(notificationName, object: nil, userInfo: imageDataDict) 

// Register to receive notification in your class
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showSpinningWheel(_:)), name: notificationName, object: nil)

 // handle notification
 func showSpinningWheel(notification: NSNotification) {
  if let image = notification.userInfo?["image"] as? UIImage {
  // do something with your image   
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the third view controller data to UserDefaults. Get data from User Defaults at first View controller :

```
`UserDefaults.standard.set(yourData, forKey: "yourDataKey")` // at third view controller

`UserDefaults.standart.string(forKey: "yourDataKey")` //first view controller
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Reason your code not working:
As soon as you move to second view controller , your third view controller is deallocated from memory. Below line has no meaning in first view controller

```
let vcThird = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "third") as! ThirdViewController //third view

    vcThird.thirddelegate = self
```

You move to second view controller , third view controller is set to nil.

1. Either you can use NSNotificationCenter to move data from third to first.
2. If you want to go with protocols, than make below code change.

Code : ViewController.swift
Remove the code:

```
let vcThird = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "third") as! ThirdViewController //third view

        vcThird.thirddelegate = self
```

ThirdViewController.swift

```
protocol thirdviewDelegate //delegate to pass data from thirs view to first view
{
    func thirdView(datas:String)
}
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    var thirddelegate:thirdviewDelegate?

    @IBOutlet var thirdTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func thirdViewInvoke(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let firstView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "first") as! ViewController //third view

        self.thirddelegate = firstView
        self.thirddelegate?.thirdView(datas: thirdTextField.text ?? "default value")
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }

}
```